# Sending the right HID Keycode?

Tags: keyboard, hid

I'm currently developing a very smal and specific HID Keyboard with a atmega microcontroller. The biggest problem i have is that a keycode is very specific for the locale that is currently set on the host pc.

All normal chars like a-z are working very well but some special chars are producing bad results when the key is pressed.

For example the `+` Key, which is `0xE1` & `0x2E` (LeftShift & KeyboardEqualSign) does only work on a US Keyboard. But i use a German Layout, so i get a `ß` instead.

How can i now get the right keycodes for the German Layout? I cant find any document that describes such keys... I think the HID Keycodes are really bad designed to support multiple keyboard layouts :(

Do i need to lookup my keys on a german layout what they would be in us? So for the `+` Sign its probably the `]` key? But why the heck its a so stupid design? Is there any wrapper for that?

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. I took a picture of an en_us keyboard and compared it to my german keyboard and then I transfered that on the keycodes... Its not yet finished because its a suprisingly lot of work and I do not need other characters right now. Most important characters should be there. Its sorted after Iso8859, I let the iso codes stay maybe that helps someone.

Here you go:

iso8859 hex code, modifier, usb hid keycode, character

- 0x22, shift,0x1F    , "
- 0x23, 0,0x31        , #
- 0x24, shift,0x21    , $
- 0x25, shift,0x22    , %
- 0x26, shift,0x23    , &
- 0x27, shift,0x31    , '
- 0x28, shift,0x25    , (
- 0x29, shift,0x26    ,
- 0x2A, shift,0x30    , *
- 0x2B, 0,0x30        , +
- 0x2C, 0,0x36        , ,
- 0x2D, 0,0x38        , -
- 0x2E, 0,0x37        , .
- 0x2F, shift,0x24    , /
- 0x30 to 0x39 are the numbers, no changes here to en_us
- 0x3A, shift,0x37    , :
- 0x3B, shift,0x36    , ;
- 0x3C, 0,0x64        , <
- 0x3D, shift,0x27    , =
- 0x3E, shift,0x64    , >
- 0x3F, shift,0x2D    , ?
- 0x40, altgr,0x14    , @
  *Upper case letter, no changes here to en_us
- 0x59, shift,0x1D    ,switch Z,Y
- 0x5A, shift,0x1C;
- 0x5B, altgr,0x25    , [
- 0x5C, altgr,0x2D    , "\"
- 0x5D, altgr,0x26    , ]
- 0x5E, 0,0x35        , ^
- 0x5F, shift,0x38    , _
- 0x60, shift,0x2E    , `
  *lower case letters, no changes here to en_us
- 0x79, 0,0x1D        ,switch z,y
- 0x7A, 0,0x1C
- 0x7B, altgr,0x24    , {
- 0x7C, altgr,0x64    , |
- 0x7D, altgr,0x27    , }
- 0x7E, altgr,0x30    , ~
  *0x80 to 0x9F not in use
  *0xA0 Not existing "non*breaking space"
- havent done yet
- 0xC4, shift,0x34 ,Ä
- havent done yet
- 0xD6, shift,0x33    ,Ö
- havent done yet
- 0xDC, shift,0x2F    ,Ü
- havent done yet
- 0xE4, 0,0x34        , ä
- havent done yet
- 0xF5, 0,0x33        ,ö
- havent done yet
- 0xFC, 0,0x2F        ,ü
- havent done yet

Hope that helps you or the next stumbling upon that problem :)

Best regards

Comment: How did you calculate it, is there any document? or can you give an example?

Comment: If I remember correctly I did find a list for the englisch keyboard and then I just mapped via pictures of the keyboards. I then verified it with a microcontroller emulating a usb keyboard using the codes. I fear I don't remember any more. I don't have any sources anymore, sorry. It was quite some time ago.